# How to centralize display grid

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, grid, responsive

I'm having trouble dealing with display: grid. I made a responsive grid for this site limiting the maximum resolution to only have 3 columns, however, when there are less than 3, the elements are thrown to the corner, and not centered. How do I fix this?

The second line has less than three. I would like that when I got less than 3 they all centered in the middle instead of being in the left corner

The paint print is a representation of what I'm wanting to do

[image: how it is]
[image: what i want to do]

## Codes

### REACT

```
    <div className={classes["wrapper"]}>
      <div className={classes["candidatos"]}>
        <h1>Candidatos pendentes</h1>
        <div className={classes["pendentes"]}>
          {candidatos.map((candidato, index) => (
            <Candidato
              showButtons={true}
              key={index}
              index={index}
              candidato={candidato}
              onAceitar={aceitarHandle}
              onRecusar={recusarHandle}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <h1>Candidatos aceitos</h1>
        <div className={classes["aceitos"]}>
          {aceitos.map((candidato, index) => (
            <Candidato showButtons={false} key={index} candidato={candidato} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <h1>Candidatos recusados</h1>
        <div className={classes["recusados"]}>
          {recusados.map((candidato, index) => (
            <Candidato showButtons={false} key={index} candidato={candidato} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### SASS

```
.wrapper
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  margin-bottom: 5rem

  h1
    color: #fff

.candidatos
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  align-content: center
  width: 100%

  .pendentes, .aceitos, .recusados
    margin-bottom: 3rem
    display: grid
    gap: 2.5rem
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)

    @media (width <= 780px)
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr)

    @media (780px < width <= 1150px)
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the grid items when there are fewer than three columns, you can add the property justify-items: center; to your grid container. This will align the items horizontally to the center of the grid cells. Here's how you can modify your SASS code to achieve this:

```
.candidatos
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  align-content: center
  width: 100%

  .pendentes, .aceitos, .recusados
    margin-bottom: 3rem
    display: grid
    gap: 2.5rem
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
    justify-items: center;

    @media (max-width: 780px)
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      justify-items: center; // Center grid cells horizontally
      justify-content: center; // Center grid cells vertically

    @media (min-width: 781px) and (max-width: 1150px)
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

By adding justify-items: center; and justify-content: center; within the media query for screen widths below 780px, you'll effectively center the grid cells both horizontally and vertically within their container when there are fewer than three columns.

Comment: Oh not a problem, see the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

As for as I can tell, you are defining three grid columns. Grids always put items inside grid areas, not **across** them. Therefore your existing CSS doesn't work.

If you want automatic centering, you need to define each row as a flex container, and style them accordingly with `justify-item: space-evenly`